# Better way to assign values to multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

this must be answered some time in the past, however I could not a particular way that I was looking for.
I want to make an array dimension of 7 x 2;

ex)

`{0,0} {0,0}
{0,0}
...
...
..
.`

```
int [,] myArray = new int[7,2];
```

Then I tried to treat each dimension of an array like one dimensional array.
So I tried to assign values to the array this way...

`int[0] = new int{ 1, 2};`

I think it should then look like...

`{1 , 2}
{0 , 0}
...
..
.`

but i get an error.

I believe it is due to my incomplete understanding of an array class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a jagged array, not a multidimentional array.  Essentially, an array of arrays:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[7][];
int[0] = new int {1, 2};
```

The second "dimension" arrays are not bounded to a length of 2 however- you need to enforce that manually. This is why they are called jagged- visually, they can be of varying lengths:

```
{
  { 3, 2 },
  { 1, 8, 3 },
  { 9, 6, 3, 4 },
  { 4, 2, 8 },
  { 4, 9, 3, 4, 5 },
  { 2, 2 }
}
```

All about arrays in C# here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it for your case:

```
int [,] arr = new [,] 
{
    {0,1},
    {1,2}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the proposition of Chris Shain, or stay with your approach which is Multidimensional array.

To initialize such array

```
int [,] myArray = new int[3,2] {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

or omit the dimension parameters

```
int [,] myArray = new int[,] {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

You problem was with accessing to the array elements, in multidimensional array you access directly to the element for example

```
myArray[1,1] = 7;
```

will change the 1 into 7;

All this and even more you will find in documentation of [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).